# How to create a new dataframe by merging columns with identical names from different dataframes in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, I want to create a new dataframe per column name from the following dataframes:

```
agedf <- data.frame(A = c(12,14,16,18), B = c(13,15,17,19), C = c(11,13,15,17))
heightdf <- data.frame(A = c(110,120,130,140), B = c(120,130,140,150), C = c(115,125,135,145))
weightdf <- data.frame(A = c(80,90,100,110), B = c(90,100,110,120), C = c(85,95,105,115))
```

The desired result is to have a formula that creates a dataframe for each of A, B and C with their respectively agedf, heightdf and weightdf columns. I.e. to end up with 3 dataframes as shown in this Excel photo:
[Excel desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYZL9.png)

How best could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a for-loop (there is probably alternatives with packaged like `tidyr` or `dplyr`):

```
newlist = list()
names = colnames(agedf)
for(i in names){
  index = which(colnames(agedf)==i)
  newlist[[i]] = cbind(agedf[,index], heightdf[,index], weightdf[,index])
  colnames(newlist[[i]]) = c("Age", "Height", "Weight")}
```

Output:

```
> newlist
$A
     Age Height Weight
[1,]  12    110     80
[2,]  14    120     90
[3,]  16    130    100
[4,]  18    140    110

$B
     Age Height Weight
[1,]  13    120     90
[2,]  15    130    100
[3,]  17    140    110
[4,]  19    150    120

$C
     Age Height Weight
[1,]  11    115     85
[2,]  13    125     95
[3,]  15    135    105
[4,]  17    145    115
```

Without using a list, and creating a new df for each `names`:

```
names = colnames(agedf)
for(i in names){
  index = which(colnames(agedf)==i)
  assign(i, cbind("Age"=agedf[,index], "Height"=heightdf[,index], "Weight"=weightdf[,index]))}
```

This gives the same output from before, just not in a list.

Lastly, if you want to add them all into a single data frame, and specify where each observation came from:

```
df = numeric()
names = colnames(agedf)
for(i in names){
  index = which(colnames(agedf)==i)
  df = rbind(df, cbind(i, agedf[,index], heightdf[,index], weightdf[,index]))}
colnames(df) = c("Code", "Age", "Height", "Weight")
df = as.data.frame(df)
```

Output:

```
> df
   Code Age Height Weight
1     A  12    110     80
2     A  14    120     90
3     A  16    130    100
4     A  18    140    110
5     B  13    120     90
6     B  15    130    100
7     B  17    140    110
8     B  19    150    120
9     C  11    115     85
10    C  13    125     95
11    C  15    135    105
12    C  17    145    115
```

Obs: you could pass the colnames `c("Age", "Height", "Weight")` directly into the `cbind` in the other approach too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using the `tidyverse`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_list <- list(Age = agedf,
                Height = heightdf,
                Weight = weightdf)

map(transpose(df_list), bind_cols)
```

```
# $A
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# Age Height Weight
# <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#   1    12    110     80
#   2    14    120     90
#   3    16    130    100
#   4    18    140    110
# 
# $B
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# Age Height Weight
# <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#   1    13    120     90
#   2    15    130    100
#   3    17    140    110
#   4    19    150    120
# 
# $C
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# Age Height Weight
# <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#   1    11    115     85
#   2    13    125     95
#   3    15    135    105
#   4    17    145    115
```